# When does the Google People API return user's country?

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I use the Google People API to find the google user's country. It returns address with populated just the `formattedValue` and `formattedType` attributes. The [docs](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.Address) state that all fields are optional. In which cases the `country` and `country_code` get populated?

Answer (score 1):

The [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/) lets you list and manage the authenticated user's [Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/) and retrieve profile information for authenticated users and their contacts.

Users edit their own contacts.  So as soon as a user adds the country for their contact the data will be populated.

Comment: I still couldn't manage to get the authenticated user's country. The Contacts product is about adding details about other people which is different than your personal contact address which can be populated here https://aboutme.google.com/u/1/ 
If you still think the Contacts product is the right one, could you direct me about how to populate the country for my profile?